Patio Stones or Composite Deck Tiles
First time poster. Hope someone can help!
Recently dug up a 10x16’ portion of my yard to build a patio for some outdoor furniture and a fire pit. I was planning all along to go 4 inches of crushed stone, 1 inch of sand and patio stones to finish but I recently stumbled across composite deck tiles. Where I live the tiles are over half the price of paver stones but I’m wondering if they’re suitable to be placed directly on the stone or sand? Websites say they are but wondering if anyone has first hand experience with it?
Bonus points if you can tell me these work in cold weather Canada. Thanks a million.

Manufacturer's instructions trump advice from strangers on the Internet; reputable manufacturers will stand by their products installed according to their instructions, but they won't care at all what advice we give you here. You really can't go wrong following manufacturer guidelines. If their install manuals and descriptions aren't clear enough, reach out to them directly.

AFAIK deck tiles need to be installed over a hard flat surface.  Can you link to an example of what you're looking at?
